# Passing value from jQuery Modal into last input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a modal window, containing a table with rows of input boxes and buttons:

```
<table class="datatable tablesort selectable paginate full" width="100%">

                       <tbody>
                                                        <tr id="row_1">
                             <td><strong><input type="text" value="120040965" id="icpcode">
     <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button></strong>
                               <p>GRAND VOYAGER WIPER MOTOR REAR 04-08 £35.00</p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>                               <tr id="row_2">
                             <td><strong><input type="text" value="120040966" id="icpcode">
     <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button></strong>
                               <p>CHRYSLER GRAND VOYAGER WIPER MOTOR FRONT 01-08 £30.00</p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>                               <tr id="row_3">
                             <td><strong><input type="text" value="120040964" id="icpcode">
     <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button></strong>
                               <p>CHRYSLER GRAND VOYAGER MK2 01-08 2.8 CRD GEARBOX AUTOMATIC £500.00</p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>                               <tr id="row_4">
                             <td><strong><input type="text" value="120040963" id="icpcode">
     <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button></strong>
                               <p>CHRYSLER GRAND VOYAGER MK2 STOW  £80.00</p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>                               <tr id="row_5">
                             <td><strong><input type="text" value="120040962" id="icpcode">
     <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button></strong>
                               <p>CHRYSLER GRAND VOYAGER MK2 01-08 WISHBONE DRIVER SIDE £15.00</p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>                           </tbody>
          </table>
```

I then use jQuery to insert the value of the inputbox (icpcode) into the last row of another table and close the open modal and focus on that inputbox:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
var value = $('#icpcode').val();

$('#tablemain tbody tr:last #itemlookup').val(value);
$('#tablemain tbody tr:last #itemlookup').focus();
$('#productlookup').modal('hide');
});
```

My problem is that only the first button works, so I need a solution that enables the selected row's value to pass back. I have incremented the tr id, but I'm not sure what I need to do... but I'm presuming it needs something involving $.(this) and also incrementing the inputbox/button. It might be easier to do away with the button and have the row itself to have an onclick? Either way I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do id give them all unique ids and then give them all the same class:

```
<button type="button" id="row 1" class="btnSave btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
<button type="button" id="row 2" class="btnSave btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
<button type="button" id="row 3" class="btnSave btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
```

Then use the class as reference and the id for the value;

```
$('.btnSave').click(function() {
    var value = this.id; // this equals 'row 1' | 'row 2' | 'row 3'

    // your remaining code here
});
```

and to get the value of the selected row's text edit, you can reference it by using the button's id to grab the value as shown below and also be ablt to create your table rows using a loop easily and fast.

```
<table class="datatable tablesort selectable paginate full" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                        <input type="text" value="120040965" id="data_1">
                        <button type="button" id="1" class="btnSave btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
                    </strong>

                    <p>GRAND VOYAGER WIPER MOTOR REAR 04-08 £35.00</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                        <input type="text" value="120040965" id="data_2">
                        <button type="button" id="2" class="btnSave btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
                    </strong>

                    <p>GRAND VOYAGER WIPER MOTOR REAR 04-08 £35.00</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                        <input type="text" value="120040965" id="data_3">
                        <button type="button" id="3" class="btnSave btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
                    </strong>

                    <p>GRAND VOYAGER WIPER MOTOR REAR 04-08 £35.00</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        $('.btnSave').click(function() {
            var row = this.id;
            var value = $( '#data_' + row ).val();

            alert( value );
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your input boxes all share the same ID and all of your buttons share the same ID. Every element on your page must have a unique ID.

```
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<input type="text" id="input3">
```

This is the reason only the first button works because it's only finding one element with that ID, and it's the first button, the rest are ignored.

So, to fix the problem, you can either add `btnSave` as a class to your buttons, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSave">
```

and change your JS to:

```
$('.btnSave').click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Or you could change your ID's very slightly, like this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSave1" class="btn btn-primary">
<button type="button" id="btnSave2" class="btn btn-primary">
<button type="button" id="btnSave3" class="btn btn-primary">
```

and your JS would be:

```
$('button[id^="btnSave"]').click(function() {
    // do something
});
```